# Polyline on Google Maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Sorry in advance for my English

I have a List routePoints that collects locations: List `routePoints`;

And where it is necessary to draw a line, I do this:

```
PolylineOptions pOptions = new PolylineOptions()     
.width(5)     
.color(Color.BLACK)     
.addAll(routePoints)     
.geodesic(true);
```

All this certainly works correctly, for example, if you walk on the sidewalk, the line is drawn slightly to the right / left of the main street. And after a while, I'm updating the line on the map and at that moment I'm on a parallel street and instead of drawing lines along the streets, it cuts off, that is, from a predetermined location to the current one, and it seems that I have passed through the buildings. I hope you understand ...) But I would like to draw lines along the streets (we go on some street, then, on the right, etc.)

[image]

I tried [android-maps-utils](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) this way:

```
String encodedLine = PolyUtil.encode(routePoints); 
List encodedList = PolyUtil.decode(encodedLine); 

PolylineOptions pOptions = new PolylineOptions()     
.width(5)     
.color(Color.BLACK)     
.addAll(encodedList)     
.geodesic(true);
```

No changes. Can anyone have a solution or opinion?

Comment: can you add some screenshots ?

Comment: @quick learner, Sorry, I could only draw, I hope it's understandable

Comment: i understand and i have worked on it , problem is that the polyline should consider the POSSIBLE path not just the distance between two successive points

Comment: @quicklearner, But how did you solve this problem?

Comment: @quicklearner, Or tell me how to correctly formulate the question, in order to search the Internet

Comment: you should look for the possible path in order to create a polyline